# Chaining spark sql queries over temporary views?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We're exploring the possibility to use temporary views in spark and relate this to some actual file storage - or to other temporary views. We want to achieve something like:

1. Some user uploads data to some S3/hdfs file storage.
2. A (temporary) view is defined so that spark sql queries can be run against the data.
3. Some other temporary view (referring to some other data) is created.
4. A third temporary view is created that joins data from (2) and (3).

By selecting from the view from (4) the user gets a table that reflects the joined data from (2) and (3). This result can be further processed and stored in a new temporary view and so on.

So we end up with a tree of temporary views - querying their parent temporary views until they end up loading data from the filesystem. Basically we want to store transformation steps (selecting, joining, filtering, modifying etc) on the data - without storing new versions. The spark SQL-support and temporary views seems like a good fit.

We did some successful testing. The idea is to store the specification of these temporary views in our application and recreate them during startup (as temporary or global views).

Not sure if this is viable solution? One problem is that we need to know how the temporary views are related (which one queries which). We create them like:

`sparkSession.sql("select * from other_temp_view").createTempView(name)`

So, when this is run we have to make sure that `other_temp_view` is already created in the session. Not sure how this can be achieved. One idea is to store a timestamp and recreate them in the same order. This could be ok since out views most likely will have to be "immutable". We're not allowed to change a query that other queries relies on.

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would definately go with the `SessionCatalog` object :
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-SessionCatalog.html

You can access it with `spark.sessionState.catalog`

Comment: Note that it is available since version 2.2.0 (it used to be private for prior versions)